# jQuery tooltip position changed after hovering again

Tags: jquery, css

I am having the following problem. The first pic shows what I expected. The tooltip popped up normally. But if I quickly hover again (mouseoff and mouseover before tooltip disappear completely), the position would change, making floating upward.

[image: Popuped normally]
[image: After Hovering link again before tooltip disappear]

I originally got the snippet of code from [jQuery UI example](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style). I've checked the CSS of `ui-tooltip` and `arrow` but found no clues. This is the CSS:

```
.ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {
    background: black;
}
.ui-tooltip {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    color: #ddd;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px black;
    border: 0;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.arrow {
    width: 70px;
    height: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35px;
    bottom: -16px;
}
.arrow.top {
    top: -16px;
    bottom: auto;
}
.arrow.left {
    left: 20%;
}
.arrow:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: -20px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 25px;
    box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow.top:after {
    bottom: -20px;
    top: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="navigation">    
        <a id="home" href="" title="Smiley Rhythmについて"><span lang='en'>Home</span></a>
        <a id="what" href="" title="リトミックとは"><span lang='en'>Rhythmic</span></a>
        <a id="lessons" href="" title="料金詳細"><span lang='en'>Price</span></a>
        <a id="schedule" href="" title="スケジュール"><span lang='en'>Schedule</span></a>
        <a id="profile" href="" title="講師について"><span lang='en'>Profile</span></a>
</nav>
```

jQuery here:

```
$(document).tooltip({
        position: {
            my: "center bottom-20",
            at: "center top",
            using: function(position, feedback){
                $(this).css(position, feedback);
                    $("<div>")
                    .addClass("arrow")
                    .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                    .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                    .appendTo(this);
                }
            }
    });
```

So where else should I check? What could be wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem the code you provide can reproduce the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/cFf7K/ (Chrome 28). Do you have a live demo somewhere that exhibits the issue you describe?

Comment: Hi yes. This is it: [http://mighty-peak-6435.herokuapp.com/](http://mighty-peak-6435.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Hm...odd, it seems to behave as desired, at least based on my testing. What browser of you using to view this problem?

Comment: I am using Chrome. The problem is gone simply after I added 'position:absolute' to 'ui-tooltip', although I still don't know exactly why.